Non radical ideal with maximal radical
I am trying to find an example of a ring $R$ with ideal $I$ such that $\sqrt{I}$ is maximal but $I$ is not radical. Indeed, I was thinking about this because it is a well known result that if $\sqrt{I}$ is maximal, then $I$ is primary, and if $I$ is both primary and radical, then it is prime. I was thinking it should be easy to think of an example where $\sqrt{I}$ is maximal but $I$ is not prime (e.g. I was trying to think of a ring that is not an integral domain where the nilradical is maximal), but I actually couldn't come up with anything.

What examples of non-radical ideals you know? Odds are, some of them have maximal radicals.

Oh of course I don't really need to think so hard about it - the simple case of $(X^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ would work right?

Looks good to me.

There are plenty of easily accessible examples. For instance, $(X^2)\subseteq \Bbb R[X]$, or $(125)\subseteq \Bbb Z$.
Often enough, you can construct an example by taking a ring $R$ and a maximal ideal $m$, and look at the ideals $m^k$ for $k>1$. That's how these examples came about. Although there are plenty of examples that don't work this way, such as $(X^3, Y^5, XY)\subseteq \Bbb R[X, Y]$.
